# How to write a statement and an array to individual lines on a text file? Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, txt

```
a = str(mergeSort(lines))
nlines = ['Sorted Numbers',a]
with open('SortedNumbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(nlines)enter code here
```

mergeSort(lines) is my array of a few numbers. With this code above, the text file it creates does everything I want except all of it is on one line. How do I get it so the text file it produces will be

```
Sorted Numbers
1
3
5
8
10
```

Comment: Don't convert the sorted list to a string.

Comment: Right.  Just use a loop to write the numbers one at a time.  You can use `print(n,file=f)`, so it provides the newline for you.

Comment: If I don't convert it to a string I get an error

Comment: Then you should post that version of the code and the error you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = "\n".join(mergeSort(lines));
```

Should put a newline after each of the numbers of your array.

It should print properly afterwards

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that the lines are already strings

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
a = mergeSort(lines)
nlines = "Sorted Numbers\n" + "\n".join([str(i) for i in a])
with open('SortedNumbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(nlines)
```

or

```
a = mergeSort(lines)
nlines = ["Sorted Numbers"] + [str(i) for i in a]  # if lines are integers
# nlines = ["Sorted Numbers"] + a               # if lines are strings
with open('SortedNumbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(nlines)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't convert the array to a string. And also write the text separately rather than trying to build an array with the title.

```
a = mergeSort(lines)
with open('SortedNumbers.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("Sorted Numbers")
    f.writelines(a)
```